# Validate Built Product - Distribution option missing in Xcode 6

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm preparing an app before uploading to Itunes Connect via Xcode 6 and I can't find something in the `Build Settings > Build Options > Validate Built Product`. In Xcode 5 there was 3 options `Debug, Distribution, Release`, in a previous project I've set `Debug` to `NO` and `Distribution` and `Release` to `YES`before I uploaded my project. I would like to ask you that is it not needed anymore? I can't find it in Xcode 6 and the Apple's guide also doesn't mention it. I would really appreciate some guidance about the topic. Is is possible that I don't need to set nowhere the `Distribution` and `Release` options anymore - not required -? (I've set the production provisioning profiles and other stuffs correctly.)

Comment: accept my answer plz  if you agree

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me.

```
1. On my machine I kept both Xcode 5 and Xcode 6 beta.

2. From Xcode 6 beta, Archive the project. Close Xcode 6.

3. Open Xcode 5, go to Organizer and export as Ad Hoc build with proper provisioning profile.
```

That's it!

Comment: I'm fine with Xcode 6 and works everything correctly, I'm just wondering that is it required or never was required and it's just an optional option.